Не понимаю проблему в коде
Решаю 5ое задание ЕГЭ ИКТ. Начал писать код, но столкнулся с проблемой. Без одной строки код отказывается работать вовсе. Ошибку я обнаружил, но не могу понять почему это работает именно так.
Вот само задание:
(А. Сардарян) На вход алгоритма подаётся два натуральных числа М и N. Алгоритм
‘строит по ним новое число R следующим образом.

Вычисляется произведение Р1 всех ненулевых чётных цифр чисел М и N.

Вычисляется произведение Р2. всех нечётных цифр чисел М и N.

Результат R вычисляется как модуль разности Р1 и Р2.
Например, для N = 256 и M = 108 получаем Р1 = 2* 6* 8 = 96 и, P2 = 5*1 = 5, так что R = |96 -
5|= 91. Укажите минимальное число М, при котором для N = 120 получается R = 29.


Мой код
def f(a):
    t=1
    for x in a:
        t*=x
    return t
p1 = 1
p2 = 1
for m in range(1,1111):
    s = map(int,list(str(m)))
    s1 = [int(x) for x in s if x%2==0 and x!=0]
    s = map(int,list(str(m))) #1
    s2 = [int(x) for x in s if x%2!=0]
    p1 = f(s1)*2
    p2 = f(s2)
    r=abs(p1-p2)
    if r==29:
        print(m)

Если убрать строку #1, то код не работает. В чем проблема?

Приведенный Вами код не будет работать, что с этой строкой, что без нее.
Преобразование должно выглядеть как-то так
s = list(map(int,str(m)))

, а не как у Вас сейчас.

Вы немного не поняли фразу "Строка #1" - имелось ввиду строку с комментарием #1. Номер этой строки 11.

Извините за неправильно составленный вопрос.

Сразу хочу сказать, что он работал только со строкой №11 (#1). Но в преобразовании действительно была ошибка. Я использовал Ваш вариант и теперь у меня нет этой проблемы. Спасибо большое за помощь, очень сильно выручили.

тогда можете отметить ответ как принятый

Вроде бы отметил.
